# Good connection establishment

Tags: java, sockets

I know that there is a good variant to use `Scanner` object when you need to get data from server during connetion. But I have question about the following code snippet:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

        try {
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = message.getBytes();
            os.write(buffer);
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }

        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

        try {
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(is);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data.append(in.next());
            }
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm confused by the snippet where `Scanner` gets data from `InputStream`, because it starts just after I send a message to the Server. Is it fair to suppose that data from the Server won't be in `InputStream` immediatelly after sending message to it?

Please, give me an advice, what is the best way to make reading data from `InputStream` in such case and what I should to take into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputStream.read()` method called by `Scanner` blocks until there is some data available. So you don't have to worry about the response time of the server.

See: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I understand now, need to find some more information about blocking and non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 0):

The code is invalid. All it does is read as much input as can be read without blocking. There is no implication that what has been read is a complete message, or corresponds to a single write() invocation at the sender, etc. If you want messages in TCP/IP you must implement them yourself, with a length word prefix, a self-describing protocol such as Object Serialization or XML, etc. etc.